# Indus Valley civilization dates back to 8000 BC or earlier - effects of the new research

Tags: history

The [latest research](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Indus-era-8000-years-old-not-5500-ended-because-of-weaker-monsoon/articleshow/52485332.cms) by IIT Kharagpur and ASI (Archaeological Survey of India) has upgraded the date of the Indus Valley civilization to 8000 BC as compared to 5500 BC as previously believed.

> In addition, researchers have found proof of a pre-Harappan
>   civilization that existed for at least 1,000 years before this (8000 BC).

What does this mean for the Hindu history? Could any of the events recorded have happened in these places?

Comment: I think you question may be closed as broad. So, please be specific to any event rather than entire history. Also, it  can give personal opinion answers.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am asking for history not opinions, if the answer is opinion based, that should be closed, not the question e.g. if XYZ place is mentioned in the scriptures and also present at one of these places - with the new information we could figure out if the event happened there. I am looking for fact based answers :)